# Get first and last item without using two joins

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

Currently I have two dataset, one is parent, and one is child. Child dataset contain "parentId" column that can link to parent table. Child dataset hold data about actions of a person, and parent table hold data about person. I want to get a dataset contain person info and his first/last action.
Dataset look like this:
Parent:

```
id | name | gender
111| Alex | Male
222| Alice| Female
```

Child:

```
parentId | time | Action
111      | 12:01| Walk
111      | 12:03| Run
222      | 12:04| Walk
111      | 12:05| Jump
111      | 12:06| Run
```

The dataset I want to produce is:

```
id | name | gender | firstAction | lastAction |
111| Alex | Male   |    Walk     |  Run       |
222| Alice| Female |    Walk     |  Walk      |
```

Currently I can achieve this using two window functions, something like:

```
WindowSepc w1 = Window.partitionBy("parentId").orderBy(col("time").asc())
WindowSepc w2 = Window.partitionBy("parentId").orderBy(col("time").desc())
```

and apply the windowSpec to child table using row_number().over(), like:

```
    child.withColumn("rank1", row_numbers().over(w1))
         .withColumn("rank2", row_numbers().over(w2))
```

The issue I have is that later, when I need to join with the parent table, I need to join two times, one for `parentId=id && rank1=1`, and another one for `parentId=id && rank2=1`

I wonder if there is a way to only join once, which will be much more efficient.
Or I used the Window function incorrectly, and there is a better way to do it?

Thanks

Comment: did my answer solved your question? If yes, please accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could join first and then use groupBy instead of window-functions, this could work (not tested as no programmatic dataframe is provided):

```
parent
  .join(child,$"parentId"===$"id")
  .groupBy($"parentId",$"name",$"gender")
  .agg(
    min(struct($"time",$"action")).as("firstAction"),
    max(struct($"time",$"action")).as("lastAction")
  )
  .select($"parentId",
           $"name",
           $"gender",
           $"firstAction.action".as("firstAction"),
           $"lastAction.action".as("lastAction")
   )
```